# Codefights: Correct solution but system does not accept it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Experienced codefighters, i have just started using Codefight website to learn Javascript. I have solved their task but system does not accept it. The task is to sum all integers (inidividual digit) in a number. For example sumDigit(111) = 3. What is wrong with my code? Please help me.

Code

```
function digitSum(n) {
    var emptyArray = [];
    var total = 0;
    var number = n.toString();
    var res = number.split("");
    for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
        var numberInd = Number(res[i]);
        emptyArray.push(numberInd);

    }

    var finalSum = emptyArray.reduce(add,total);

    function add(a,b) {

        return a + b;

    }

    console.log(finalSum);
    //console.log(emptyArray);
    //console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is correct, so this must have something to do with how the Codefighters website works. Could you try replacing `console.log(finalSum);` with `return finalSum;`?

Comment: This probably belongs on Code Review. But the problem with your code is most likely that you're converting the number to a string to break up the digits. There's a much more efficient way to do that that involves only arithmetic and a loop.

Comment: pzp, you are right i'm having the same feeling....my algorithm is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a faster trick for summing the individual digits of a number using only arithmetic:

```
var digitSum = function(n) {
  var sum = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  return sum;
};
```

`n % 10` is the remainder when you divide `n` by `10`. Effectively, this retrieves the ones-digit of a number. `Math.floor(n / 10)` is the integer division of `n` by `10`. You can think of it as chopping off the ones-digit of a number. That means that this code adds the ones digit to sum, chops off the ones digit (moving the tens digit down to where the ones-digit was) and repeats this process until the number is equal to zero (i.e. there are no digits left).

The reason why this is more efficient than your method is that it doesn't require converting the integer to a string, which is a potentially costly operation. Since CodeFights is mainly a test of algorithmic ability, they are most likely looking for the more algorithmic answer, which is the one I explained above.

Comment: Thanks it was great help!